# GetView method does not get called

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin, baseadapter

I'm trying to display a listview in a viewflipper. however the GetView() method never gets called. i'm not sure if this has anything to do with it but i have more then one adapter. however the first one does work. here is my adapter code :

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Android;
using Android.App;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using CardAppReal.Lib.Models;

namespace CardAppReal.Assets
{
    public class SetAdapter : BaseAdapter<Set>
    {
        List<Set> items;
        Activity context;
        public SetAdapter(Activity context, List<Set> items)
            : base()
        {
            this.context = context;
            this.items = items;
        }
        public override long GetItemId(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }
        public override Set this[int position]
        {
            get { return items[position]; }
        }
        public override int Count
        {
            get { return items.Count; }
        }
        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            var item = items[position];
            View view = convertView;
            if (view == null) // no view to re-use, create new
                view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(NavigationDrawerTest.Resource.Layout.rowlayout, null);
            view.FindViewById<TextView>(NavigationDrawerTest.Resource.Id.Text1).Text = item.Name;
            view.FindViewById<TextView>(NavigationDrawerTest.Resource.Id.Text2).Text = item.CardAmount + " Cards";
            view.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Argb(150, 153, 217, 234));
            return view;
        }

    }
}
```

and here is the method i create my stuff in :

```
private void OnSerieListItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            vf = FindViewById<ViewFlipper>(Resource.Id.viewflipper);
            var listView = sender as ListView;
            var t = Series[e.Position];
            Android.Widget.Toast.MakeText(this, t.Series, Android.Widget.ToastLength.Short).Show();
            LoadSets(t.Series);
            vf.DisplayedChild = 2;


        }

        private async Task LoadSets(string serie)
        {
            SetDataService setDataService = new SetDataService(new SetRepo());
            Sets = await setDataService.GetSetAsync(serie);

            var listViewSets = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.ListViewSets);
            //drawerLayout = FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.drawer_layout);
            listViewSets.Adapter = new SetAdapter(this, Sets);
            listViewSets.ItemClick += OnSetListItemClick;

        }
```

the items.count in the adapter is never 0 so i am not sure why it is not getting called.

EDIT:

when i debug it i noticed that it jumps in the count method several times in a row. not sure if this has anything to do with it. however it never shows 0 so it should do the getview.

EDIT2:

this is my axml for the listview. the layout axml should be working just fine since i'm using the same one in my first adapter and it works fin in there.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <TextView
    android:text="Test Sets"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


  <ListView
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/ListViewSets" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Change BaseAdapter<Set> to BaseAdapter

Comment: @Roy this gives me issues on the method public override Set this[int position]

Comment: which method is showing error??

Comment: The indexer one I presume.

Comment: @Roy also my other adapter does have the <> after BaseAdapter and works fine

Comment: Didn't find any problem with your adapter, is that possible that your `Sets` which is passed to adapter as a `List<Set>` is null or empty?

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT the Sets i am giving the adapter is never empty when i debug. the variables are always filled in and everything looks just fine. is it because i try loading a second adapter in the same activity?